# Magento 2 : Set My Account Page Title with customer name

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account, page, page-title

I want to change page title of **My Account Page** only like below:

> welcome back, Customer.firstname()

How I can change my account page title only with customer firstname?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by pluginize exceute method. Try following way:

1. Create plugin[Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Index">
        <plugin name="Vendor_Module::my_account" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Customer\Controller\Account\Index" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

2. Now create class [Vendor/Module/Plugin/Customer/Controller/Account/Index.php]

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Customer\Controller\Account;

class Index
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $sessionSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $sessionSession
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $sessionSession;
    }

    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Index $subject,
        $resultPage
    ) {
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Welcome back %1', $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getName()));

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Clear cache.

Comment: I have tried the above code, I have created the same files and directory structure in the `app/code/MyVendor/Mymodule` but it's not working. Please suggest if I am going wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I have just tried to format you answer with the color code. Please ignore it.

Comment: Did you create module? that means 'Vendor\Module'?

Comment: Check here https://ranasohel.me/2014/03/07/creating-a-custom-module-in-magento-2/, after that follow this answer.

Comment: Verndor => your vendor name, Module => your module name, Got It?

Comment: Yes, I have created the module in the `app/code`.

Comment: You mean I need to create module in the `app/design/vendor/theme` or `app/code/vendor/module`?

Comment: Yes, I have created the module in the app/code -> yes. Please check carefully, it should work.

Comment: after all done browse http://your_url/customer/account.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to complete @Sohel Rana answer. In the magento version I use (2.4.5-p1) I had to set the block title to empty. Otherwise it will always take the title set in layout instead of the controller.

in your theme folder :
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/customer_account_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
      <action method="setPageTitle">
        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string"></argument>
      </action>
    </referenceBlock>
  </body>
</page>
```